# How to get model from REST endpoint in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller, sapui5

My rest client is as follows:

```
com.sap.lm.sl.slp.Proxy.prototype.loadAttributes = function(oInput) {
com.sap.lm.sl.slp.ajax.checks.assertString(oInput.id);
oInput.url = '{0}/service/attributes/id/{1}'.format(this.baseUrl, oInput.sid);
oInput.adapter = function(oResponse, oInput) {
    return oResponse;
};
return com.sap.lm.sl.slp.ajax.GET(oInput);
};
```

The controller is as follows:

```
 _appendAdditionalDetails: function() {
        var that = this;
        window.ctx.Client.loadAttributes ({
            sid: that.getid(),
            success: function(additional) {
```

How can I get the value from get to the controller. How to declare the model in SAP UI5

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of the response, you may either opt to use a [JSONModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) or an [XMLModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel.html). If the data is in neither format (XML / JSON), then you should try and transform it to one of them.

In the `onInit` method of your controller, you should instantiate the appropriate model and register it to your view. Example:

```
onInit: function() {
    // the second parameter is the model name / alias
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(), "myModel");
}
```

In your controller method where you call the REST endpoint, you should obtain the model declared in the `onInit` method and then update its data (either by completely overwriting the existing data or by modifying it; it depends on what you need).

```
_appendAdditionalDetails: function() {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel("myModel");
    window.ctx.Client.loadAttributes ({
        sid: this.getid(),
        success: function(additional) {
            oModel.setData(additional);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to completely replace the existing data, use the `setData` method. Otherwise, use the `setProperty` method (and write the data in some sub-tree of the model).